# Why is my OS not showing up under the Startup and Recovery Page?

Tags: windows-7, bcd

I had a triple boot situation where I deleted the system reserved partition.  I was able to get it back by following a gentleman's advice when I asked this question:

[Removing Linux Partition on Windows 7 machine](https://superuser.com/questions/276792/removing-Linux-partition-on-Windows-7-machine)

I just recently realized that Windows 7 doesn't show up in the startup and recovery window shown below.  How do I get it to show up there.  I tried EasyBCD but it says that it cannot find a BCD store.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could use "Dual-boot Repair" utility that comes with Visual BCD Editor - download here [Windows 7 Boot Configuration Data Editor](http://www.boyans.com).

The tool repairs Windows 7 boot environment automatically - writes MBR and Windows 7 PBR to active partition and creates/repairs BCD store. This makes Windows 7 boot by default.

Creating Windows (XP, Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8) loaders is again a one click task - run Visual BCD Editor and select "Create missing windows loaders".

To add an entry for Linux (Ubuntu, Fedora) see the "How to".

Comment: -1 You're link does not go to a windows 7 Boot Configuration Data Editor site.  It is instead a art drawing site.